# Mongoose.js creates multiple connections to MongoDB from one connect() call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a single connection to MongoDB via Mongoose in Node.js Express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
```

I then define schema, followed by models, and lastly the controller that pulls all users from the database:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  return User.find(function (err, users) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(users);
    }
  });
});
```

These DB connections open during the application start and they stay open for the duration of the node.js application.

What bothers me is why do I have 5 connections open? As soon as I close the node.js app, all 5 connections are closed.
[image]

**Related note**: For a REST API server is it better to have MongoDB connection always open. Or is it better to manually open/close connections per each user request?
d

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's because Mongoose uses a pool of 5 connections (by default) that are shared throughout your application.  For best performance, it's best to just leave them open.

You can alter the default behavior via the options parameter to `mongoose.connect`.  For example:

```
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test', { server: { poolSize: 3 }}); // Use 3 connections
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was going crazy trying to figure out why it kept opening 5 connections at a time.

Comment: @Benny mongodb server is able to handle multiple requests simultaneously, especially for read requests (This ability is more available when the server has more than 1 replicas). However, one connection keeps responsibility for only 1 request

Answer (score 1):

Add this if statement to check only when mongoose disconnected, try to connect it

```
if (Mongoose.connection.readyState === 0)
       mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
```

readyState contain these types :

```
0: disconnected
1: connected
2: connecting
3: disconnecting
```